# Automatically creating textboxes based on number of rows

Tags: vba, excel, textbox, userform

Is there a way in VBA Excel Userform to automatically create textboxes on the userform based on the number of rows on a particular sheet?

My data is in Sheet 1 starting from A1, being:

- A1: Invoice Date
- B1: Invoice No.
- C1: Invoice Amount
- D1: Payment Received

Now there are many rows of data (invoices) and there is no way one can know how many rows relate to a particular customer. The Payment received textboxes would be empty when the userform loads while Invoice Date, Invoice No. and Invoice Amount would be taken from Sheet 1.

Then it would be very easy to fill the the payment received textboxes payments can be applied to a particular invoice.

Comment: The answer to your question is yes - there is a way. You didn't ask how, but a simple answer is to find the number of relevant rows and then have VBA add that amount of rows when loading the userform.

Comment: How ? Of course, I posted the question from "how to do it" perspective. Thanks

Comment: What have you tried @StarShines?  http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: Scott, I am not a full-fledged software developer or programmer. I am an accountant and posting a generic question here for learning purposes. I wonder why everyone here is not following your wisdom of problem-solving. Your kind comment is well noted by the way. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

If you have a spreadsheet like this:

[image]

You can add a click handler to the Show Form button:

```
Sub FormButton_Click()
    TestForm.Show
End Sub
```

And within the TestForm code:

```
Option Explicit

Const dateCol = 1
Const invoiceNumCol = 2
Const amountCol = 3
Const paymentCol = 4

Private Sub SaveButton_Click()
    Dim row As Range
    Dim box As Control

    For Each row In ActiveSheet.Rows
        On Error GoTo ExitHandler
        row.Cells(1, paymentCol).value = Me.Controls(row.row & paymentCol).value
    Next row

ExitHandler:
    Exit Sub
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim row As Range

    For Each row In ActiveSheet.Rows
        If row.Cells(1, dateCol).value = "" Then
            Exit For
        End If

        Call AddBox(row, dateCol)
        Call AddBox(row, invoiceNumCol)
        Call AddBox(row, amountCol)
        Call AddBox(row, paymentCol)
    Next row
End Sub

Private Sub AddBox(row, colIndex)
    Dim box As Control

    Const width = 50
    Const padWidth = width + 4
    Const height = 15
    Const padHeight = height + 4
    Const topMargin = 25
    Const leftMargin = 5

    Set box = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", row.row & colIndex)
    box.Left = (colIndex - 1) * padWidth + leftMargin
    box.height = height
    box.width = width
    box.Top = (row.row - 1) * padHeight + topMargin
    box.value = row.Cells(1, colIndex).value
End Sub
```

The form will appear like this:

[image]

Values can be entered into the Paid column, and they will be copied to the spreadsheet when the Save button is clicked.

To explain the logic, it loops through each populated row, creates the appropriate controls, and populates the values. In the Save routine, the rows are again looped through, and the payment values are copied back to the spreadsheet.

Comment: Hi Drew ...Thank you for this code. Its working fine except for 2 things: (1) A1, B1 and C1 contains headers. (2) Since we wont know exactly how many invoices there will be for any customer, the userform only shows textboxes as per its own height. In other words, if 30 invoices, then 30 textboxes of for example date, if 58 invoices, then 58 textboxes of Invoice numbers. The number of invoices is variable. Thanks

Comment: The code will generate as many rows of text boxes as there are invoice rows- reading your question, that seems to be what you're looking for, yes? As for the header, just add an offset, which can be done by wrapping the contents of the `For`  loop of the `Initialize` method with a check: `If row.row > 1 Then`

Comment: I don't know how to add image here but I am afraid the rows of textboxes are not the same as invoice rows. You can try it yourself by adding more data (may be more rows like 15,35,...etc) and see if it works or not, or may be, they are not visible on the userform due to userform height

Comment: @StarShines I think you'll have to add more detail to your question, including some code, possibly screenshots, and a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Best of luck!

Comment: I just said that the userform is not showing all textboxes, it has to have a scrollbar to go down in case we have many invoices. Thanks for your help though :)

Answer (score 0):

Assume a form named "frmMain" then to add 4 text boxes the following sub routine should do it:

```
Private Sub AddTextBoxes()

Dim ctlTextBox As MSForms.TextBox
Dim intCol, intCols As Integer
Dim strCName As String

' Determine number of columns
intCols = 1
Do While Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, intCols).Value <> ""
    intCols = intCols + 1
Loop

' Add text boxes
For intCol = 1 To intCols - 1
    strCName = "txtC" & intCol
    Set ctlTextBox = frmMain.Controls.Add("Forms.Textbox.1", strCName)

    With ctlTextBox
        .Top = 10
        .Width = 50
        .Height = 20
        .Left = (intCol) * 60
        .Value = intCol
    End With

Next

' Assuming there is a column 1 (i.e. "Invoice Data") the control name will be "txtC1"
' This box can be set by:

frmMain.Controls("txtC1").Value = 999



End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time, but its giving me a blank userform.

Comment: Create a command button on the form and within the Private sub CommandButton1 add the new line AddTextBoxes. When you click the button in the opened form it should call the sub AddTextBoxes

Comment: Dear Reg, I have added the code. Now when I run the userform and click the command button, 3 textboxes apper and showing values such as 999, 2, 3

Comment: May be I was unable to explain properly. The userform when loads should take the data from Sheet 1 and present it into textboxes as explained in my original post. Now if there are 30 rows of data with 3 columns, the userform is to create 90 textboxes with scrollbar and those textboxes would include data from Sheet 1, A2 to C31

Comment: I should have added that I misread your original post (didn't realise until after I posted) as I based my answer on the number of columns! Sorry. That said, the key code is the "Set ctlTextBox=..." line. This enables you to add controls to your form. The code within the With/End With block simply formats the text box.

Comment: P.S. I can answer your amended request but won't be able to do so until tomorrow evening if that's okay?

Comment: No problem, please take your time and thank you very much for everything :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above, add a frame to frmMain called "fmeMain" and set the following properties for fmeMain thus:

ScrollBars = 2 - fmScrollBarsVertical
ScrollHeight = 800

Add a command button to frmMain called "cmdTest". Add the following subroutines to the frmMain's code module:

```
Private Sub AddTextBoxes()

Dim ctlTextBox As MSForms.TextBox
Dim intCol, intRow, intTop As Integer
Dim strCName As String

intTop = 10

For intRow = 2 To 31        ' Assumes that row 1 contains header

    For intCol = 1 To 3

        strCName = "txtC" & intCol & "R" & intRow
        Set ctlTextBox = frmMain.Controls("fmeMain").Add("Forms.Textbox.1", strCName)

        With ctlTextBox
            .Top = intTop
            .Width = 50
            .Height = 20
            .Left = 52 * intCol
            .Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(intRow, intCol).Value
        End With


    Next

    intTop = intTop + 25

Next


End Sub



Private Sub cmdTest_Click()

AddTextBoxes

End Sub
```

Comment: This should not be a new answer, but rather an update to your existing answer.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts Reg. Highly appreciate that :)